# mounted method is fired before data loaded - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, lifecycle, vue-resource

I'm using [Vue Resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/) to retrieve an images collection from a REST API. The request is sent in the `created` hook of my Vue component.

The problem is, I'm trying to access the retrieved data in the `mounted` hook, but the data isn't loaded.

I get this error in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Here is my component:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { imgs : '' };
  },
  created() {
    // the full url is declare in my main.js
    this.imgs = this.$resource('acf/v3/pages/4');

    this.imgs.query().then((response) => {
      console.log('success', response);
      this.imgs = response.data.acf.gallery;
    }, (response) => {
      console.log('erreur', response);
    });
  },
  mounted() {
    // get the ref="image" in my dom template
    let imgs = this.$refs.image;

    imgs.forEach((img) => {
      // I do some stuff with imgs
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

If I wrap a `setTimeout` around the content of `mounted`, everything works fine.

So, I don't understand how I can wait for my data to load before the `mounted` hook is executed. Isn't this the role of the Vue lifecycle hooks?

Comment: why don't you just use created()?

Comment: Because nothing is reactive in `created`. You can't manipulate the DOM before `mounted` hook. [check this documentation](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/). And this is exactly the same issue if I use only one lifeCycle hook. My content isn't loaded when I would like to use it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the `this.imgs.query()` call is async, your `mounted` hook is being called before the `then` handler is setting `this.imgs` (which I'm assuming is being bound with `v-for` to an element in your template with an attribute `ref="image"`). So, even though the component has been mounted to the DOM, the `$refs` have not been set up yet.

I would make a method to "do some stuff with imgs" and then call that method in a [`$nextTick` callback](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) in the `then` handler of the async call. The callback passed to `$nextTick` will be "executed after the next DOM update cycle", meaning the `$refs` will be set up at that point.

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { imgs: '' };
  },
  created() {
    // the full url is declare in my main.js
    this.imgs = this.$resource('acf/v3/pages/4');

    this.imgs.query().then((response) => {
      console.log('success', response);
      this.imgs = response.data.acf.gallery;
      this.$nextTick(() => this.doStuffWithImgs());
    }, (response) => {
      console.log('erreur', response);
    });
  },
  methods: {
    doStuffWithImgs() {
      // get the ref="image" in my dom template
      let imgs = this.$refs.image;

      imgs.forEach((img) => {
        // I do some stuff with imgs
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't know [$nextTick](https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#Vue-nextTick).  Thanks, it's working as expected right know.

Comment: @thanksd is this how its usually done because i guess all vuejs app some way or other use data from some api and then create dom based on it.i want to know is this how its done usually

Comment: @anekix There are many ways to handle general async behavior in a Vue app. If you need to affect data in the `this.$refs` array before the component has been mounted, then yes, using `$nextTick` is the best and most common way.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the [Lifecycle Diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) of Vue instance. After Mounted Hook (which means we can access DOM), there is also `beforeUpdate` and `updated` hooks. These hooks can be used when data is changed. I think `beforeUpdate` or `update` hook can be used after getting data in created hook.

```
<script>
   export default {
      data() {
         return { imgs : '' };
       },
   created() {
    // the full url is declare in my main.js
    this.imgs = this.$resource('acf/v3/pages/4');

    this.imgs.query().then((response) => {
        console.log('success', response);
        this.imgs = response.data.acf.gallery;
       }, (response) => {
         console.log('erreur', response);
     });
   },
  // here we can use beforeUpdate or updated hook instead of mounted
  beforeUpdate() {
    // get the ref="image" in my dom template
    let imgs = this.$refs.image;

    imgs.forEach((img) => {
    // I do some stuff with imgs
   });
 }
}
```

I hope this helps.